# appenChild is not a function in my php page

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello everyone why it returns "appenChild is not a function?"

```
function showBooks(ajax) {
         var books = ajax.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("book");
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var titleNode  = books[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    var authorNode = books[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0];
    var title  = titleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var author = authorNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var year = books[i].getAttribute("year");

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = title + ", by " + author + " (" + year + ")";
    $("books").appendChild(li);
}
```

In a page where i don't include theese it works. If I include theese js it doesn't work. I need all theese javascript

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

I can't work so much on javascript, sorry

Comment: Why are you including jquery.min.js twice? In your example you have it pulling one from an https address and another from a folder named vendor.

Comment: appendChild() is not available on jQuery object. try .append() instead and yeah @RyanWilson is right remove extra script loading jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

`$("books")` is a jQuery Object, not a HTMLElement, so it does not have HTMLElement Methods, like `appendChild`. What jQuery Objects have is [`$(...).append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), which works for your case:

```js
function showBooks(ajax) {
  var books = ajax.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("book");
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = books[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    var authorNode = books[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0];
    var title = titleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var author = authorNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var year = books[i].getAttribute("year");

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = title + ", by " + author + " (" + year + ")";
    $("#books").append(li); // use jQuery append method instead of appendChild
  }
}
```

Or you can get the underlying HTMLElement, and use `appendChild` on it:

```js
function showBooks(ajax) {
  var books = ajax.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("book");
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = books[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    var authorNode = books[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0];
    var title = titleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var author = authorNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var year = books[i].getAttribute("year");

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = title + ", by " + author + " (" + year + ")";
    $("#books").get(0).appendChild(li)); // use appendChild on the HTMLElement
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. The error desappear but it doesnt print what I want to print.

Comment: Which method did you use? What is $("books")? Since that can't really be valid HTML. Did you try removing the second jQuery from your HTML?

Comment: If i remove the second jQuery my navbar doesn't work properly (i don't know why, is a template that i found on internet).
$("books") is  <ul id="books"> on the php file.

Comment: That would be `$("#books")`

Comment: Okay... If the answer helped you solve the problem, please mark the question as answered ;-)